# Adding an event to particular date on calendar and want to highlight that date

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-calendar

In my android app, I have an Activity by name **AddEventActivity** in which I'm adding an event with a date and save it on local storage(SQLite). Now I want to show that event on calendar with highlight.

The link which I'm following is
[here](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/sample/BasicActivityDecorated.java)

So please help me out.

Comment: Try a Custom Calendar....it is much easier and compact than you think : https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Comment: Okay..i will try..@DakshAgrawal

Comment: Thanks @DakshAgrawal..its work like charm..cheers

Comment: Upvote my comment please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Custom Calendar....it is much easier and compact than you think : https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want

Thanks to AHMED AL-AMIR. I use it in [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dakshansh.partytimevendorsapp&hl=en) App.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Decorators to add events to the Calendar view library you are using.
For more information check their documentation:

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/DECORATORS.md